# Creating custom post type for wordpress online store

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I creating a theme for WordPress,
I have tried [this tutorial](https://theme4press.com/create-wordpress-custom-post-types-programmatically/#attachment%20wp-att-24859/0/) on creating WordPress custom post, and also did some research but struggling to find a clear answer(on custom post)

I am trying something like this:

```
+----------------------------+
|Post-type:   Books          |
+----------------------------+
|Name:        Les misérables |
|Author:      Victor Hugo    |
|Genre:       Poesy          |
|Year-of-Pub: 1862           |
+----------------------------+
```

How can I create a custom post that allow me to add, remove and edit a book and all the details related to it. And display it as any post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new post type in Wordpress is pretty easy, you just need to edit the modify the right files, what I normally do is create a new plugin (which is simply a new folder in the wordpress folder system), create a php file inside your plugin folder with the same plugin name.

here is the code to create an empty post type, that in your case it's gonna be "book"

```
<?php
function dwwp_register_post_type() {
   $args = array('public'=> true, 'label'=> 'Staff');
   register_post_type( 'staff', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'dwwp_register_post_type' );
```

if you want to specify more information for your custom post type:

```
<?php
//Exit if accessed directly
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
function dwwp_register_post_type() {

$singular = 'Job';
$plural = 'Jobs';
$slug = str_replace( ' ', '_', strtolower( $singular ) );
$labels = array(
    'name'          => $plural,
    'singular_name'     => $singular,
    'add_new'       => 'Add New',
    'add_new_item'      => 'Add New ' . $singular,
    'edit'              => 'Edit',
    'edit_item'         => 'Edit ' . $singular,
    'new_item'          => 'New ' . $singular,
    'view'          => 'View ' . $singular,
    'view_item'         => 'View ' . $singular,
    'search_term'       => 'Search ' . $plural,
    'parent'        => 'Parent ' . $singular,
    'not_found'         => 'No ' . $plural .' found',
    'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No ' . $plural .' in Trash'
    );
$args = array(
    'labels'              => $labels,
        'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 10,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-businessman',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'delete_with_user'    => false,
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'map_meta_cap'        => true,
        // 'capabilities' => array(),
        'rewrite'             => array( 
            'slug' => $slug,
            'with_front' => true,
            'pages' => true,
            'feeds' => true,
        ),
        'supports'            => array( 
            'title', 
            'editor', 
            'author', 
            'custom-fields' 
        )
);
register_post_type( $slug, $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'dwwp_register_post_type' );
```

Also have a look to this tutorial if you struggle... http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress

good luck.

Comment: Thx for useful link and explanation. I also found http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-custom-meta-boxes-in-wordpress-posts-and-post-types/